# What can I do to access to the properties of an object inside a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash

I have an array named `sportPromise` which looks like:

```
0: Array[0]
1: Array[1]
2: Array[2]
3: Array[3]
```

doing `console.log(angular.toJson($scope.sportPromise, 'pretty'));` returns

```
[
  [],
  [
    {
      "id": 5932,
      "parent": 1000,
      "name": "NBA",
      "sport": {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "NBA"
      },
      "lineType": "G",
      "priority": [
        1,
        3
      ],
      "part": "0"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 2599,
      "parent": 1000,
      "name": "NCAA BASKETBALL",
      "sport": {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "College Basketball"
      },
```

I need to access the `name` property of the object nested in that array, which as you can see is a nested array also.

Any suggestions?

I'm using `lodash` with Angular.

Comment: `$scope.sportPromise[0][1].name`

Comment: not that easy mt friend, still getting ```undefined```.

Comment: can you set a breakpoint in the debugger and use the console in devoloper tools to explore the collection?

Comment: sorry I got the `[1][0]` backwards :) `$scope.sportPromise[1] is the array containing the object you want. The object is at index 0, and from there you can access the "name" property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it by iterating through each nested scope:

```
for (var i=0; i< sportPromise.length; i++) { 
   for (var j=0; j < sportPromise[i].length; j++) { 
      console.log( sportPromise[i][j]['name'] );
   }
}
```

Comment: just one more question, and what about if I want to access to the full array ? not just the name

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: yes I mean, the trick yo gave me is to access to the ```"name"``` only, what about accessing to the whole properties on that array instead?

Comment: All of the properties of the object (id, parent, sport, etc...) are available at the same level - replace 'name' by whatever you need to use.

Comment: and what about If need all the properties at the same time ?

Comment: Take a quick read through the JavaScript Guide's section on [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects). You're never really working with all of the properties _at the same time_, at most you're holding a reference to the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the property with`$scope.sportPromise[n][0].name`.

Comment: just one more question, and what about if I want to access to the full array ? not just the name

Comment: Which array are you talking about?

Comment: the second one, instead of only accessing the name, I would like to access to the full whole properties on that array

Comment: I think you mean `Object`, not array. You can access it with `$scope.sportPromise[n][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the `name` attributes, you can easily extract that with lodash's [flatten](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) and [pluck](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) functions:

```
_.chain(sportPromise).flatten().pluck('name').value()
// -> ["NBA", "NCAA BASKETBALL"]
```